# Restricting Previous Dates in DatePicker Dialog Android

Tags: android

I want to customize the DatePicker dialog which i am using in my Android application so that it allows the user to select only the current and the future dates. Is there any way this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like setMinDate and setMaxDate may be what you are looking for.

setMinDate(long)
Sets the minimal date supported by this NumberPicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)